# printing log of jar on timeout in python

Tags: python, jar, subprocess

I have a requirement to execute a jar, and also have a timeout mechanism around it , such that when a timeout occurs, the exeuction stops.
On my research I found that we can use the 'timeout' attribute of subprocess.call()
To replicate my usecase, I have a jar which prints a message every second for 15 seconds.
Now the python application is coded as below.

```
import subprocess
X1 = subprocess.run(['java', '-jar', 'JarsForPython2.jar'],timeout=15)
print('------------checks for stdout-----------------------')
print(X1.stdout.decode())
print('------------checks for stderr-----------------------')
print(X1.stdout.decode())
```

Everything works smooth. Now to check for the timeout, I make the changes and set timeout=7
I modify the code and handle the exception as below

```
try:
    X1 = subprocess.run(['java', '-jar', 'JarsForPython2.jar'], capture_output=True, timeout=7.0)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
    print('The execution has timedout')
else:
    print('------------checks for stdout-----------------------')
    print(X1.stdout.decode())
    print('------------checks for stderr-----------------------')
    print(X1.stderr.decode())
```

Now here, I get

```
The execution has timedout
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I just want to have the output of the first six seconds log here on my console.
Any suggestion?

Comment: maybe you should use `finally:` instead of `else:`. When you get error then it not execute `else:`

Comment: there can be other problem - when it gets error `TimeoutExpired` then it doesn't assing process to `X1` and you can't get output. It may need something more complex.

Comment: it seems you will have to use `e.stdout.decode()` in `except`

Answer (score 1):

`else:` is executed only when there was no error.

I found that in `except:` you can get `e.stdout` and `e.stderr` but you have to check if it is not `None`.

```
import subprocess

try:
    X1 = subprocess.run(['java', '-jar', 'JarsForPython2.jar'], capture_output=True, timeout=7)    
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
    print('The execution has timedout')
    print('------------checks for stdout-----------------------')
    if e.stdout:  # check if not `None`
        print(e.stdout.decode())
    print('------------checks for stderr-----------------------')
    if e.stderr:  # check if not `None`
        print(e.stderr.decode())
else:
    print('------------checks for stdout-----------------------')
    print(X1.stdout.decode())
    print('------------checks for stderr-----------------------')
    print(X1.stderr.decode())
```

or with `finally`

```
import subprocess

try:
    X1 = subprocess.run(['java', '-jar', 'JarsForPython2.jar'], capture_output=True, timeout=7)
    stdout = X1.stdout
    stderr = X1.stderr
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
    print('The execution has timedout')
    stdout = e.stdout
    stderr = e.stderr
finally:
    print('------------checks for stdout-----------------------')
    if stdout:  # check if not `None`
        print(stdout.decode())
    print('------------checks for stderr-----------------------')
    if stderr:  # check if not `None`
        print(stderr.decode())
```